# Can I run an ASP.NET app in a virtual directory under an OrchardCMS instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, orchardcms

As the title suggests, we are tasked with running a custom .NET MVC application in a virtual directory under the client's Orchard CMS installation. Now, I've successfully done this type of thing in the past with two custom .NET MVC applications, but never with Orchard. Orchard does some unique things behind the scenes, so I do not believe it would be possible.

Two things:
 1. I can't build a new Orchard instance from source.
 2. It must be a virtual directory on the same domain for SEO purposes. Running the site on a subdomain is bad for Google rankings. Therefore http://www.example.com/myportal is good, whereas http://myportal.example.com is really bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. While this isn't specific to Orchard, you're likely going to run into some issues with web config inheritance. Depending on the individual scenarios you face (such as shared assemblies but different versions...duplicate config nodes etc) you should be able to search around on stackoverflow and resolve those easily though.

Resource: [Virtual directory inside Orchard web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369625/virtual-directory-inside-orchard-web-application)

Comment: Did you run into any other issues, @captain-kenpachi ?